# Is it possible to develop extensions for visual studio 2012 using free tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix

I would like to make a template for F# lib + XNA 4.0 + Xbox360 for visual studio 2012.
All I have is Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition for Web.
When I try to install the Visual Studio 2012 SDK, it stops after reporting that it requires Visual Studio 2012. The log seems to indicate it's looking for the Professional edition.

I'm not interested in buying a professional license for hobby work, and I am a bit surprised Microsoft would want to prevent hobbyists from extending their product.

I do have a professional license for Visual Studio 2010, though. If there's a way to make extensions for 2012 using 2010, that would work for me.

Comment: Express just doesn't support add-ins, the buck stops there.

Comment: Yet there is an entry "Extensions and updates" under tools. It's at least possible to install new templates from the visual studio gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VS2010 to develop extension compatible with VS2012.
All you have to do is to manually change vsixmanifest to make it work with newer version:

```
<SupportedProducts>
      <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
```

Note however that Visual Studio Express does not support extensions, so you won't be able to install it in VS2012 Express anyway.

Comment: Visual Studio Express does support extensions, at least some of them. For instance, you can install new project templates from the visual studio gallery.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Some extensibility is allowed albeit very limited.